# ReferenceError: exit is not defined at repl:1:1 (in node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

So I'm just trying to do a very basic Hello World server with this code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');})
.listen(port, host, function(){
    console.log('Server Running on http://' + host + ':' + port);
})
```

When I try to save and quit in Sublime I get this error:

```
Error trying to parse project. Expected value in C:\Users\Austin\HelloWorld.js:1:1
```

I tried using another text editor and it let me save the code, but when I run it in REPL I get no console log and no Hello World page, although something is still running. I'm using the most recent version of node.js for Windows x64.

Comment: Try running it this way: `node C:\Users\Austin\HelloWorld.js`. Your code looks fine.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Running what I had originally should be fine if I'm already in REPL, right?

Comment: Sometimes newlines throw things off in the REPL...if you want to test it in the REPL, try replacing all the newlines with spaces first.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting this: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)

Comment: Not sure...maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227486/node-repl-throws-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Matt Browne's first answer was correct after all!

Sublime is somehow my issue, and when I tried his suggestion I was using an old version of the js file which is why it didn't work when I tried it.